# node.js - Does calling the callback terminate the current function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to call a `util` function that might encounter an error. In case of an error the `process` function should be terminated. The only way to throw an error properly is the `callback` function.

I would terminate the function by returning, but since I am in the `util` function, the `process` function will continue after the `util()` call.

```
function util(callback) {

    // do something synchronous

    if (err) {
        // doesn't terminate the process function
        // since we are in the util function
        return callback("something unexpected happened");
    }
}

function process(callback) {
    util(callback);
    console.log("This should not be printed if an error occurs!");
}

process(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        // this has to be executed in case of an error
        console.log(err);

        // terminate the process function somehow?
    }
});
```

Comment: I assume you mean **a**synchronous in `util`, as otherwise you wouldn't use callbacks?

Comment: @Bergi I use the callback because it's passed to process by code that's not under my control.

Comment: I guess then only `process` should call the callback, and `util` should be a standard synchronous function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you make a few changes to your code

```
function util(callback) {

    // do something synchronous

    if (err) {
        // doesn't terminate the process function
        // since we are in the util function
        callback("something unexpected happened");
        return false;
    }

   return true;
}

function process(callback) {
    if(!util(callback)) return;
    console.log("This should not be printed if an error occurs!");
}
```

Comment: Your console.log will still print regardless of what happens. Or rather, it may or may not print regardless of what happens in Util.

Comment: Since i return false, it wont print if the function has an error. You can try it out.

Comment: You are trying to return true/false inside the timeout function, so the return will be to the timeout not to your original function, check this https://jsfiddle.net/r37okyt9/1/

Comment: My bad, quite correct. However, I'm still unconvinced that you have guaranteed the order of callbacks. This only works if util returns before js calls console.log. If the util function takes a while (what I was trying to achieve with the timeout) then it will call console.log before process returns and cancels itself, because return statements don't guarantee synchronous functionality.

Answer (score 3):

> Does calling the callback terminate the current function?

No, a callback is just a regular function. It might of course throw an exception (although that is despised).

> I want to call a util function that might encounter an error. In case of an error the process function should be terminated.

For that, you need to check in the callback what did happen and act accordingly. You could use [`process.exit`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code) for termination.

```
function myProcess(callback) {
    util(function(err, result) {
         if (err) {
             callback(err);
         } else {
             console.log("This should not be printed if an error occurs!");
             callback(null, result);
         }
     });
}

myProcess(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        // this has to be executed in case of an error
        console.log(err);
        process.exit(1);
    }
});
```

Notice that promises could simplify this a lot, as they distinguish between success and error callbacks. `util` would have to return a promise for that:

```
function util() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        // do something asynchronous

        if (err)
            reject("something unexpected happened");
        else
            resolve(…);
    });
}

function myProcess() {
    return util().then(function(res) {
        console.log("This should not be printed if an error occurs!");
        return res;
    });
}

myProcess().catch(function (err) {
    // this has to be executed in case of an error
    console.log(err);
    process.exit(1); // you might not even need this:
    throw err; // The node process will by default exit with an unhandled rejection
});
```

Comment: process.exit() does not help in my case because the application runs a webserver and that should keep running.

Comment: @MaxMustermann Ooops, I have confused "*terminate the process function*" with "*terminate the process*". In case you just don't want to do anything else, use `return` (possibly after calling a callback to signal you're done, if your function is async).

Answer (score 0):

No, you will want to do something like this:

```
            function util(callback) {
                // do something synchronous
                if (err) {
                    throw new Error('Something unexpected happened');
                }
                callback(); // only execute callback if an error did not occur
            }

            function process(callback) {
                try{
                    util(callback);
                    console.log("This should not be printed if an error occurs!");
                } catch(error){
                    process(error);
                }
            }

            process(function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    // this has to be executed in case of an error
                    console.log(err);
                    process.exit(1)
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a good time to use a Promise, promises are Javascript's way of forcing a synchronous function. Basically you set it up like this:

```
var util = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    /* do some stuff here */

    if (someCondition) {
        resolve("With a message");
    } else {
        reject("with a message");
    }
}

function process() {
    util.then(function() {
        console.log("Won't call if there is an error");
    }).catch(function() {
        console.log("There was an error, Bob");
    });
}
```

Comment: You must pass functions to `then`

Comment: You're still not passing a function, but `undefined`. If you want to name the functions, please use `onFulfill` and `onReject`.

Comment: @Bergi - Goodness I'm tired. Now edited for correctness.